# Merging redundant tags with JavaScript. (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm creating a middlewhere between systems, and get outdated html like the following:

```
<font size="4">Step 1: This is a </font><strong>step</strong><font size="4">.</font>

<ol style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;">
    <li>This is my first substep.</li>
...
```

ol starts the steps, but the first line defines the name. I need to convert line 1 to:

```
<font size=4>Step 1: This is a step.</font>.
```

In some cases, there may be a span after the last font tag, but there will never be a font tag that isn't in the step title. It is crucial that it follows the

```
<font size=4> Step 1: ... </font> or <font size=4> Pre-Step 1: ... </font>
```

format. I am using jQuery.

Comment: Is there an element that wraps the whole first line? Then you could just do `$('selector for that element').text()` and it will get your the text without any tags. Otherwise, you're going to end up having to iterate through the DOM, counting and matching `font` elements, or (horror!) use regex.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: If there could be only two successive `font` element ou can get the latter using the `font + font` selector then get the first using `$(this).prev().first()`.